# Create EpsGraphics2D from Graphics2D

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics2d

I am using the http://sourceforge.net/projects/jlibeps/ library.

I have an existing Graphics2D object that is already drawn onto, and then want to create a new EpsGraphics2D object from the Graphics2D object.

Is this possible, or any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

The jlibeps author provided this example, but I fail to understand how the `paint(g)` line can accomplish this:

```
//If you want to paint a Graphics2D in an EPS file, you can do that:
FileOutputStream finalImage = new FileOutputStream(file);
EpsGraphics2D g = new EpsGraphics2D("Title", finalImage, 0, 0, 500, 500);
paint(g);
g.flush();
g.close();
finalImage.close();
```

Comment: [most of instructions are described in authors sited :-)](http://jlibeps.sourceforge.net/manual.html)

Comment: I read those instructions - they didn't help me. I.e. How does paint(g) accomplish the rendering of a Graphics2D object to EpsGraphics2D?

Comment: `they didn't help me.` , for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), because someone can has some experiences with this 3rd.party library

Comment: please to check this forum and to search [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+paint) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+paintcomponent) , for real background to read [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) , examples are [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/Catalog0261__2D-Graphics.htm) , notice tons examples or are outdated (`changes in API`), for `Swing JComponents` to use `paintComponent()`, for `AWT paint()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a `Graphics2D` object in general won't help you, as it allows you to *draw* to some medium, but not to *read* what is currently rendered to that medium, much less what instructions were used to draw the current content.

Instead, you have to feed a `EpsGraphics2D` object into the pipeline just the same way you would a `Graphics2D` object for screen rendering. Usually you want to draw the content of some component. That can be done by calling its [`paint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#paint%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method. So by calling that `paint` method with your constructed eps graphics object, you can cause all painting instructions to go to the eps file. That is what the `paint(g)` line in the manual refers to.

To phrase this differently: you do not need an existing `Graphics2D` object which you magically turn into an `EpsGraphics2D` object. Instead, you need a chain of method calls which does something useful to a `Graphics2D` object, i.e. renders some content to it. Then you can re-use that code to generate an eps file by passing a `EpsGraphics2D` object (which is simply a special case of a `Graphics2D` object, and hence of a `Graphics` object) to the outermost invocation of that code.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I was hoping to have a single Graphics2D object from which I could then generate different files, PNG and EPS in this case.